# XCUIElementQuery that will match all instances of a custom class

Tags: ios, xcuitest

I replaced all the instances of `UISwitch` in my app with a custom class - let's call it `MySwitch` - and as a result the `XCUIElementTypeQueryProvider.switches` query doesn't contain any results.  How can I create a query that *does* match all descendants that are instances of `MySwitch`?

Ideally what I want is to be able to call `someElement.switches` and have it return all instances of `UISwitch` and `MySwitch`, or call `someElement.mySwitches` and have it return all instances of `MySwitch`.

Answer (score 0):

You’d need a way to uniquely identify your switches since presumably they are now coming back as `otherElement` and a query for all of those would return a lot of junk (depending on your app). Add an accessibility ID of `mySwitch` (or anything you'd like) to your switch and you should be able to get them all back with `myElement.otherElements[“mySwitch”]`.

If you need a query that returns both your custom switches (found by an identifier) AND standard switches you're going to have to come up with a compound predicate. I've made a guess at what the second predicate should be (not tested / never written an elementType predicate so you might have to play around a bit), but it'd be something like this:

```
let mySwitchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier = %@", "mySwitch")
let standardSwitchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "elementType = %@", ".switch")
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [mySwitchPredicate, standardSwitchPredicate])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  The accessibility identifier approach is what I'm doing right now and it's adequate for writing my test cases, but it's not the solution I'm looking for because it breaks down if I want to have a unique identifier for a specific switch - such an element would be findable by its unique identifier, but wouldn't come up with the generic query.

If that means there's no solution to my problem, as I've strictly defined it, then at least I'll have learned the limits to which the UI testing framework can be pushed.

Comment: Yes, as you’ve found non-standard components are more difficult to work with. Perhaps your switches are contained in uniquely identifiable objects (like a cell you can add an ID to for each switch) and you can use those to find them?